# What does it mean to return an enum with the same name as the string parameter?

Tags: java, enums, tostring, enumeration

My professor wants us to make an enum called MedicalSpecialty, with GENERAL_MEDICINE, PEDIATRICS, and ONCOLOGY as members of the enumeration (so far so good).

Then he wants us to define a method called getFromString inside the MedicalSpecialty enum "that takes a String parameter and returns a MedicalSpecialty with the same name as the String parameter"

I'm not sure what he means, but then he says:

"Hint: use the toString() method from the MedicalSpecialty enum to perform your checks"

I'm not looking for a solution, but rather an explanation of what he is asking, if anyone understands. Is the getFromString method meant to take in a String like "general_medicine" and then output "GENERAL_MEDICINE" as type MedicalSpecialty? That seems useless and probably wrong...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What would you expect `MedicalSpecialty.getFromString("GENERAL_MEDICINE")` to return?

Comment: Basically, what they're asking you to do is write a look up method that takes a `String` value representing one of the valid enum "names" and return an instance of that enum value.  Personally, `valueOf` would work better then `toString`, but that's me...

Comment: It's not fair that new compsci's have stackoverflow to help them. Just. Not. Fair.

Comment: Well I'm not in computer science, but I do appreciate your responses! Especially @MadProgrammer !

Comment: @Jona I'd hardly call myself a computer scientist, may be a computer breaker ;)

Comment: Hard to see what the pedagogical point is when the compiler already writes one for you. Is he going to treat 'return MedicalSpecialty.valueOf(param);' as a wrong answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea. Think of it this way:

Suppose you are designing a system that works with components that function across the globe and you use the internet to communicate between them. A component in Europe, wants to request a new doctor of Oncology to be transferred from the US component. It can't send a MedicalSpeciality enum over the wire, so instead it sends a String, e.g. "Oncology". Now, in the code of your US component, you want to translate that piece of text to something that your US component system understand: the enum.

You need to write a method that takes the input String sent over the wire and returns the corresponding Enum value.

Comment: That explains it perfectly! thank you very much. I really was struggling more with the "why would he ask us to do this". Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jona "why would he ask us to do this" in java enum is a better way to  represent a finite set of constants. In your example the design decision is to create a finite set of constants for representing specialties and then to be able map a string representation of specialty to an enum

Comment: So in the enum class I made a loop that searches through the names to find a match (I ended up using a toString) and it works fine. But in my main method when I try to do MedicalSpecialty spec = new MedicalSpeciality(); it says it cannot instantiate the type MedicalSpecialty - but I'm meant to (in the main) do something like "spec.getFromString("PEDIATRICS") -- so what am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: You don't create an instance of enum type. Instead you write a factory  method in the enum and use it to get an instance of enum.

Comment: @SriniKandula saved the day again! to make this work I had to turn my enum method to "Static" - do you know why that is?

Comment: You can not create an enum using the constructor. Hence the factory method with static signature is useful http://tinyurl.com/kjjp3k2.

Answer (score 0):

He means that valid input for your function will be the following:

"GENERAL_MEDICINE", "PEDIATRICS", "ONCOLOGY"

Your task is to convert the type String to the type Enum.

Answer (score 0):

He probably wants you to show that you know how to loop through all the elements of an enum and compare each toString result to the passed in string.

You're right, that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Medicine {

    GENERAL_MEDICINE("general_medicine"), 
    PEDIATRICS("pediatrics");

    private final String value;

    Medicine(String v) {

        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Medicine fromString(String v) {
        for (Medicine c : Medicine.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```